# Pandas dataframes subsetting performance optimization

Tags: pandas

I need to subset dataframe rows on the basis on multiple conditions. Each condition is described by a set of columns. Say, there are columns 
`size_10ml`
`size_20ml`
`size_30ml`
and there will be `1` in only one of the columns and zeroes in all others.
So to choose items (rows) by size and brand I will pass `[["size_10ml", "size_20ml"], ["brand_A", "brand_E"]]` to the following function:

```
def any_of_intersect_columns(df, *column_lists):
    """ Choose rows ANDing multiple conditions. I.e. choose rows having nonzero value in at least one of the columns
    in all sets.

    column_lists : Each argument is iterable. It is is a list of column labels. 
                   A row meets condition if any of labeled columns from the current list is true.
                   Then rows from each condition (list) are intersected

    Return
    -----
    df :  subset of df rows
    """

    by_row = df 
    for columns in column_lists:
        # choose columns of interest
        try:
            by_col = df[columns]
            # leave rows, evaluating True in at least one of chosen columns
            by_row = by_row.loc[by_col.any(axis=1), :]
        except KeyError:
            error("None of columns has labels {}".format(columns)) 
            by_row = pd.DataFrame()
    # return all, if nothing fits conditions
    return by_row if by_row.shape[0] else df
```

The function is called a few times for different condition "levels" to choose one item and there are many items, all from one table. I need ways to optimize this since this is the performance bottleneck.

Data and output example:

```
>>> df
   size_10ml  size_20ml  brand_A  brand_E  property_1
0          1          0        1        0           0
1          0          1        0        1           1
2          0          1        1        0           0
>>> any_of_intersect_columns(df, [["size_10ml", "size_20ml"], ["brand_A"]])
>>> [0, 2]
```

Finally it is possible to refactor to have string property values in columns instead of ones and zeroes but I think this can slow down things only.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: asongtoruin done